# How to read from App.config when overwriting ProtectedConfigurationProvider

Tags: c#, .net

In order to centralize my configuration settings in a database, I have
created a custom class which inherits from ProtectedConfigurationProvider.
From within the ProtectedConfigurationProvider::Decrypt() function, I then
read all keys and values from the database.

I would like to keep a few specific keys and values in the local app.config file. How can I access these values from within my custom class without creating an infinite loop?

If I try to access my local configuration values as follows:

```
string test = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test.String"].ToString();
```

from inside my
ProtectedConfigurationProvider::Decrypt() function, I get an infinite loop.

Note: I want to keep my keys/values inside the appSettings section
but it looks like it EncryptedData is the only tag that can be contained within.

```
<appSettings configProtectionProvider="CustomProtectedConfigProvider">
    <EncryptedData></EncryptedData>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to provide the closest thing to an answer I can. Keys cannot be placed within the

```
<appSettings></appSettings>
```

tags since they can only contain the EncryptedData tag. However, keys and values can be saved within the

```
<configProtectedData><providers></providers></configProtectedData>
```

section. When the overridden ProtectedConfigurationProvider::Initialize() function is called, these keys and values can be accessed via the "config" parameter without 
causing an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code snippet may hep you

```
Configuration objConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        AppSettingsSection objAppsettings = (AppSettingsSection)objConfig.GetSection("appSettings");

        if (objAppsettings != null)
        {
            objAppsettings.Settings.Add("hello", "world");
            objConfig.Save();
        }
```

Comment: I want "hello" and ”world” to exist in the appSettings section upon startup. With this solution, wouldn't I have to pull them from somewhere else?